# Is it possible to remap an XBOX 360 controller button in Windows 10 without third-party tools?

Tags: windows-10, game-controller

I'm using Windows 10 with an XBOX 360 controller, and I would like to remap one of the physical buttons on controller to a different command/function. I've been searching for a few months and I am loathe to install 3rd party utils, which seems to be the general solution offered up by the net. Is it at all possible to do this within Windows itself, sans 3rd party utils?

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down, but it is on-topic for this site and fits well within the rules. Sometimes people downvote without reading, which might have happened.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Moses. Yeah, I was a bit confuzzled about the sudden negative. Also trying to feel your way around a new UX is weird, so it took me about 10 mins to figure out that I can reply here, instead of clicking anywhere on your post or name :) heh.